# How to pass an array of strings in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a command line interface for a school project. I have a `driver.cpp` to run the command line and that parses the commands into an array of strings for the `commandInterpreter`. When I try to debug it looks like only the first string is getting passed when I call `interpreter->interpret(rowData, length);` If I type "import p filename" in the command line, it looks like `args` only contains the string "import". I am expecting it to be passed {"import", "p", "filename"}. Am I passing or accessing the array of strings incorrectly?

**Driver.cpp**

```
#include "CommandInterpreter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   CommandInterpreter * interpreter = new CommandInterpreter();

   while ( !interpreter->terminate() )
   {
      string cmd;
      getline(cin, cmd);

      //Parse command args to lowercase
      int i = 0;
      while(cmd[i])
      {
         char c = cmd[i];
         putchar(tolower(c));
         i++;
      }
      //Parse command line into command and parameters.
      //Space delimited.
      stringstream ss(cmd);
      string item;
      string * rowData = new string[100];
      int length = 0;
      while (getline(ss, item, ' ')) {
         rowData[length] = item;
         length++;
      }

      //Interpret command
      interpreter->interpret(rowData, length);
      //Print feedback
      cout << interpreter->feedback() << '\n';
   }

   delete interpreter;
   return 0;
}
```

**CommandInterpreter.h**

```
#ifndef __COMMANDINTERPRETER_H
#define __COMMANDINTERPRETER_H

#include <string>
#include "ProjectController.h"
#include "LocationController.h"
#include "VolunteerController.h"
#include "ScheduleGenerator.h"
#include "VolunteerScheduler.h"

class ProjectController;
class LocationController;
class VolunteerController;
class ScheduleGenerator;
class VolunteerScheduler;

using namespace std;

class CommandInterpreter
{
public:
   CommandInterpreter(void);
   ~CommandInterpreter(void);

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Tells the driver when to teminate the program.
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool terminate(void);

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Interprets the given array of commands.
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool interpret(string * commands, int length);

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Provides feedback for the last command run.
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   string feedback(void);

private:
   bool exitFlag;
   string handback;

   ProjectController * PC;
   LocationController * LC;
   VolunteerController * VC;
   ScheduleGenerator * SG;
   VolunteerScheduler * VS;

public:
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Interprets a save command.
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool save(char arg0);

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Interprets an import command
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool import(char arg0, string filename);

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Interprets a print command.
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool print(char arg0, char arg1);

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Interprets a schedule command.
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool schedule(char arg0);

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Interprets a help command. Provides a list of commands in feedback.
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool help(void);
};

#endif
```

**CommandInterpreter.cpp**

```
#include "CommandInterpreter.h"

CommandInterpreter::CommandInterpreter(void)
{
   exitFlag = false;
   handback = "";
   PC = new ProjectController();
   LC = new LocationController();
   VC = new VolunteerController();
   SG = new ScheduleGenerator();
   VS = new VolunteerScheduler();
}


CommandInterpreter::~CommandInterpreter(void)
{
   delete PC;
   delete LC;
   delete VC;
   delete SG;
   delete VS;
}


bool CommandInterpreter::terminate(void)
{
   return this->exitFlag;
}


bool CommandInterpreter::interpret(string * args, int length)
{
   //args should be an array of strings like {"import","p","filename"}
   //Debug only shows "import"

   string cmd = args[0];
   handback = "";

   if(cmd == "exit")
   {
      exitFlag = true;
   }
   else if(cmd == "save")
   {
      this->save(args[1][0]);
   }
   else if(cmd == "import")
   {
      this->import(args[1][0], args[2]);
   }
   else if(cmd == "print")
   {
      if(length == 2)
         this->print(args[1][0], '0');
      else
         this->print(args[1][0], args[2][0]);
   }
   else if(cmd == "schedule")
   {
      this->schedule(args[1][0]);
   }
   else if(cmd == "help")
   {
      this->help();
   }
   else
   {
      this->handback = "Invalid Command. Type help to see commands.";
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}


string CommandInterpreter::feedback(void)
{
   return this->handback;
}


bool CommandInterpreter::save(char arg0)
{
   bool success = true;

   switch (arg0)
   {
   case 'p':
      // PC->save();
      handback = "Saved project schedule.";
      break;
   case 'v':
      // VC->save();
      handback = "Saved volunteer schedule.";
      break;
   default:
      // Uh-oh
      handback = "Invalid argument for save: " + arg0;
      success = false;
      break;
   }
   return success;
}

bool CommandInterpreter::import(char arg0, string filename)
{
   bool success = true;
   switch (arg0)
   {
   case 'p':
      PC->importCSV(filename);
      handback = "Imported projects file: " + filename;
      break;
   case 'l':
      LC->importCSV(filename);
      handback = "Imported locations file: " + filename;
      break;
   case 'v':
      VC->importCSV(filename);
      handback = "Imported volunteers file: " + filename;
      break;
   default:
      success = false;
      handback = "Invalid argument for import command: " + arg0;
      break;
   }
   return success;
}


bool CommandInterpreter::print(char arg0, char arg1)
{
   bool success = true;
   switch (arg0)
   {
   case 'p':
      // PC->print()
      // or project schedule print
      // depending on arg1
      if(arg1 == '0')
         handback = PC->getProjectStrings();
      else
         ;   //Print project schedule here.
      break;
   case 'l':
      // LC->print()
      break;
   case 'v':
      // VC->print()
      // or volunteer schedule print
      // depending on arg1
      break;
   default:
      success = false;
      handback = "Invalid argument for print command: " + arg0;
      break;
   }
   return success;
}


bool CommandInterpreter::schedule(char arg0)
{
   bool success = true;
   switch (arg0)
   {
   case 'p':
      // SG->generate()
      handback = "Project schedule generated.";
      break;
   case 'v':
      // VS->generate()
      handback = "Volunteer schedule generated.";
      break;
   default:
      success = false;
      handback = "Invalid argument for schedule command: " + arg0;
      break;
   }
   return success;
}


bool CommandInterpreter::help(void)
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Why all the pointers and `new`? Did somebody tell you to do that?

Comment: Looks like pointless objectification to me...

Comment: Looks like somebody is using Java or C# techniques in C++.

Comment: `args` is a variable, of type `std::string*`. I doubt it contains any string.

Comment: You know there's no garbage collector in C++?

Comment: As soon as you did this: `CommandInterpreter * interpreter = new CommandInterpreter();` that convinced me you've been reading too many Java or C# books, or haven't shaken the Java habit of using `new`.  There is absolutely no need for `new` there: `CommandInterpreter interpreter;` is all you need.  I can bet that most, if not all of those other places where you're using `new` can be replaced with objects.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, so many issues, so little time...

**Unnecessary dynamic memory allocation**
`CommandInterpreter * interpreter = new CommandInterpreter();`
You use `std::string` without dynamic allocation, so why this one here?
Also, you should use a `unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` that has pointer and memory management handling if you must dynamically allocate.

If the object is to big for a local variable, declare it as `static`.

**Using '\0' for std::string termination**
The '\0' is a C-style string terminator.  When you use `getline`, it fills a `std::string` object with text.  The `std::string` does not use a nul character for string termination.  Change your `while` loop to use iterators or make it a `for` loop with length:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cmd.length(); ++i)
{
  cmd[i] = std::tolower(cmd[i]);
}
```

But why use a loop when you can use `std::transform` to convert all the characters.  Search the web or StackOverflow for "c++ transform tolower".

**Pass `std::vector` not arrays**
As you have found out, passing arrays to functions is difficult, especially the syntax.  Vectors are so much easier:

```
std::vector<std::string> commands;  // Look Ma, no *new* operator.
CommandInterpreter(commands);
```

**Passing arrays**
Remember that an array name can decay to the address of the first slot.  Also, you need to pass the capacity along with the number of elements in the array:

```
void CommandInterpreter(string * array, unsigned int items_in_array, unsigned int array_capacity);
```

Or

```
void CommandInterpreter(std::vector<std::string>& array); // Much simpler using vector.
```

**File naming conventions**
You use a different extension for C++ headers. The ".h" suffix has historically been for C language header files.  For example, the following is valid in a C language ".h" file:

```
typedef struct class
{
  unsigned int cout;
  double       private;
} class_t;
```

Your header file would do strange things when compiled for C language.

Some conventions use ".hh", or ".hpp" to denote a header file is for C++.

**Improve readability with variable names**
The two letter variables are not readable.  Choose longer variable names.  If you chose two letter abbreviations because its too long to type, take a keyboarding class.

**Use initialization lists**
You can use the `new` operator in an initializations list, which reminds me...

**Check memory allocation for errors**
Every dynamic memory allocation needs to be checked for success.  This can be performed by checking the pointer for NULL or catching an exception.  Also verify your implementation set up on whether or not `new` throws an exception.  Some compilers allow you to turn off the exception throwing.

**Not every function needs to be in an object**
Some object oriented languages enforce a rule that functions must be in a class.  The C++ language is different, you can have functions outside of classes called "free standing functions".  Try it!

Enough for now ...